# Databinding List<Object> WindowsPhone

Tags: windows-phone

I would like to improve my productivity to use the correct design.
So I add a folder SampleData and a file RestaurantsSampleData.xaml
The structure of this file defines :

```
 xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:GeolocationTest.ViewModels">
<vm:MainViewModel.Pois>
    <vm:Poi Id="1" Adresse="20 rue de vinci, 33700 merignac" Name="MacDonald" />
    <vm:Poi Id="2" Adresse="20 rue de vinci, 33700 merignac" Name="MacDonald"/>
    <vm:Poi Id="3" Adresse="20 rue de vinci, 33700 merignac" Name="MacDonald"/>
    <vm:Poi Id="4" Adresse="20 rue de vinci, 33700 merignac" Name="MacDonald"/>
    <vm:Poi Id="5" Adresse="20 rue de vinci, 33700 merignac" Name="MacDonald"/>
    <vm:Poi Id="6" Adresse="20 rue de vinci, 33700 merignac" Name="MacDonald"/>
    <vm:Poi Id="7" Adresse="20 rue de vinci, 33700 merignac" Name="MacDonald"/>
    <vm:Poi Id="8" Adresse="20 rue de vinci, 33700 merignac" Name="MacDonald"/>
    <vm:Poi Id="9" Adresse="20 rue de vinci, 33700 merignac" Name="MacDonald"/>
    <vm:Poi Id="10" Adresse="20 rue de vinci, 33700 merignac" Name="MacDonald" />
</vm:MainViewModel.Pois>
```

And my class Pois is

```
   public class PoiDetail : PoiBase
{
    public String FormattedAddress { get; set; }        
    public String FormattedPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public String Icon { get; set; }
    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to add a list in my RestaurantsSampleData.xml to permit to display in the designer of visual studio. Currently I don't find any way to do it and I loose many time between build the application, check the design and modify it.
It will more effective to use sample and after plug the real data.

Comment: the answer is on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374632/binding-sampledata-windowsphone

Answer (score 0):

Use blend to create your sample data if you have it with your copy of Visual Studio 2013

1. Create a new windows phone silver light project
2. Create new Sample Data

Described in this link...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee341450(v=expression.40).aspx

3. Drag and drop the Collection onto the mainpaige.xaml

Change the data context of your list when you run the application to see the actual data