# Binding Sampledata WindowsPhone

Tags: binding, windows-phone-8

I have a simple class with a property List Photos. You know by default in many sample of code you find a sampledata. Each time, it presents a simple property as a string. This sampledata is used to populate the designer and you can see the render without to compile.
So I try to find a way to have a sampledata with a List filled. 
I try to use the functionnality from Blend permitting to generate data but it doesn't work with List.

You can see below the code generate. It miss the property List.
And I don't find any documentation explaning clearly the binding in details.

```
<ViewModels:ItemViewModel xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:RssReader.ViewModels" 
                      Description="Aliquam aenean integer quisque mauris" 
                      Link="Maecenas vivamus" 
                      Title="Praesent curabitur aliquam nullam phasellus"/>
```

My assumption is I need to add something as

```
<ViewModels:ItemViewModel xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:RssReader.ViewModels" 
                      Description="Aliquam aenean integer quisque mauris" 
                      Link="Maecenas vivamus" 
                      Title="Praesent curabitur aliquam nullam phasellus"                           
                      <Photos x:Key="strings" Type="sys:List" 
                                xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
                                <sys:String>Photos1</sys:String>
                                <sys:String>Photos2</sys:String> >
                    </Photos>
```

But it's not the correct syntax. Can you provide an help to solve it.
This topic is link to the subject [Databinding List<Object> WindowsPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345683/databinding-listobject-windowsphone)

Best regards,
Alexandre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [working with Design and Runtime Data for Windows Phone](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/07/12/design-time-data-for-windows-phone.aspx).